# Data preparation for scikit learn decision tree

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to prepare a dataset for scikit learn, planning to build pandas dataframe to feed it to a decision tree classifier.

The data represents different companies with varying criteria, but some criteria can have multiple values - such as "Customer segment" - which, for any given company, could be any, or all of: SMB, midmarket, enterprise, etc. There are other criteria/columns like this with multiple possible values. I need decisions made upon individual values, not the aggregate - so company A for SMB, company A for Midmarket, and not for the "grouping" of customer A for SMB AND midmarket.

Is there guidance on how to handle this? Do I need to generate rows for every variant for a given company to be fed into the learning routine? Such that an input of:

```
Company,Segment
A,SMB:MM:ENT
```

becomes:

```
A, SMB
A, MM
A, ENT
```

As well as for any other variants that may come from additional criteria/columns - for example "customer vertical" which could also include multiple values? It seems like this will greatly increase the dataset size. Is there a better way to structure this data and/or handle this scenario?

My ultimate goal is to let users complete a short survey with simple questions, and map their responses to values to get a prediction of the "right" company, for a given segment, vertical, product category, etc. But I'm struggling to build the right learning dataset to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'company':['A','B'], 'segment':['SMB:MM:ENT', 'SMB:MM']})
expended_segment = df.segment.str.split(':', expand=True)
expended_segment.columns = ['segment'+str(i) for i in range(len(expended_segment.columns))]
wide_df = pd.concat([df.company, expended_segment], axis=1)
result = pd.melt(wide_df, id_vars=['company'], value_vars=list(set(wide_df.columns)-set(['company'])))
result.dropna()
```

Comment: Thank you, and while this does pretty much address the "mechanical" aspect of expanding out the subcategories to individual rows, my fundamental question is - is such an expansion REQUIRED at all? Or is there another way to prepare this data before feeding it to a decision tree that will get valid results? perhaps I need to rephrase my question to make that aspect more clear, but your code is valid and does properly expand the grouped criteria should that be required.